# Shortcut to access intellisense in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umqiv.png)This is the menu/selector that I am referring to. It has been bugging me for days. It shows up as you begin to write the name of the function or variable you want but after I press space I cant get it back without typing the variable/function name from the beginning. Is there a shortcut for it, I cant seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Does Control+Space work?

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. This has been bothering me for some time, so I appreciate it